# How to export typescript enum with systemjs and Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to use Angular2 with system.js and typescript. It's been working fine for the interfaces I've been exporting so far, but as soon as I try to import an enum it all blows up. In the following code, `Card` works fine, but when I import `Legend` I get the error `GET http://localhost:3000/shared/legend 404 (Not Found)`.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {CardService} from './card.service';
import {Card} from '../../shared/card';
import {Legend} from '../../shared/legend';

@Component({
    selector: 'cards-list',
    templateUrl: 'app/cards-list.html',
    providers: [CardService]
})
export class CardsListComponent implements OnInit {
    public cards:Card[];

    //using Legend is the problem!
    public legendValues:String[] = [Legend[Legend.ARIANE]];

    constructor(private _cardService:CardService) {
    }
    getCards() {
        this._cardService.getCards(cards => this.cards = cards);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getCards();
    }
}
```

Here is the legend file:

```
export enum Legend {
    THE_RAPTOR,
    LINZA,
    ARIANE,
    OZAN
}
```

Why can't I import a normal enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's been working fine for the interfaces I've been exporting so far, but as soon as I try to import an enum it all blows up

Interfaces are a *compile time only construct* and therefore have no *runtime impact*. The files with the interfaces are *not loaded at runtime*. However files with runtime stuff *like `classes`/`variables`/`enums`* etc. are loaded at runtime and you are getting a 404 on these. This is a server setup error. You need to allow loading these JS files.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I have an additional issue with my typescript target being ES5 and that not supporting enums as far as I can tell, but that's another issue entirely!

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and eventually fixed it by exporting a 'dummy' class before my enum...

`

export class L{};

export enum Legend {
    THE_RAPTOR,
    LINZA,
    ARIANE,
    OZAN
}

...

import {L, Legend} from '../../shared/legend';
`

Unfortunately I can't say why this was necessary (although I have seen remarks that enums without a class are not allowed why not?!) but it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In the bellow code I'll demonstrate how to ***EXPORT*** class (***constClass***) contain list of const that can be used in your class service.

*-serviceAngularClass.js-*

```
    ...
    import {WsRessources} from "./constClass";

            @Injectable()
            export class PersonneService {...

        public functionName():Observable<any>{
            return this.updateRessource(WsRessources.BasePath+WsRessources.affectLeavingDate...);


        }
}//end Class
```

*-constClass.js-*

```
    export class WsRessources {
        public static BasePath='personnes';
        public static affectLeavingDate='/affectLeavingDate';
     }
```